# Shiny scoping rules - where to load libraries in modular architecture

Tags: r, module, shiny, package

With this question I'm only interested in obtaining some clarity on a best approach to using packages while working with a Shiny app. Despite the fact that, contrary to good practice on asking [R-related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1655567), the question does not contain code or reproducible example, I hope that it touches on practical and relevant matters.

## Problem

I'm working on a [modular](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) Shiny app that has the following structure:

- `server.R` - contains some key functions and first few initial graphics
- `ui.R` - provides basic user interface framework
- **`data`** - folder with some data files that are not sourced dynamically

  - `list.csv` - sample file with data
  - `...` - other data files
- **`functionsAndModules`** - folder with `*.R` files pertaining to functions and modules

  - `functionCleanGeo.R` - simple function cleaning some data frames of format: `cleanDataFrame <- function(data) { ... return(cleanDta) }`
  - `moduleTimeSeries.R` - module providing time series analysis doing the following things:

    - generating user interface
    - sourcing data
    - generating charts
  - `...R` - other modules and functions saved as `*.R` files.

### Libraries

What I would like to know is how to approach loading packages that would be most optimal for the app structure outlined above. In particular, I would like to know:

1. When it's sufficient to load libraries **only** in `global.R` and when (if at all) it may be required to load libraries across module files and/or `server.R` / `ui.r`?

   1.2. For example when using [**`shinyTree`**](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyTree) package I load it in `server.R` and `ui.R` as, it is my understanding that this flows from examples. Modules and functions use `dplyr` / `tidyr` combination, *would it be sufficient to load those packages in `global.R`*?
2. My preferred method for loading packages looks like that: 
   `Vectorize(require)(package = c("ggvis", "SPARQL", "jsonlite", "dplyr", "tidyr", "magrittr"), character.only = TRUE)`, will it work fine with the architecture described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here my two cents:

- Packages to load need to be declared at the start of the `app.R` file, at the server side of the `app.R` or alternatively at the modules file.
- At the modules, the libraries can be declared either outside of the `fooUI` and `fooServer` module functions or inside. Both works.
- For re-usability of the modules, I prefer to declare them at the start of each `module*.R` file.
- At least for me, libraries loaded on the `global.R` file, **do not** get to the modules, so they can run. My hypothesis is that it doesn't load on the app.R environment. I understood that the global.R is to load share objects from `server`and `ui` and to [set some configuration](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html).

Comment: Thanks, very useful comments. I prefer to use to file architecture `ui.R` / `server.R`; would you then suggest pushing everything into the two files? I'm thinking whether this is efficient as the `require` / `load` calls would be executed twice. Your answer provides some useful insight and valid suggestions so in the absence of more comprehensive answers I will be happy to accept.

Comment: If you have the structure `ui.R` / `server.R`, I will suggest to declare them at the `ui` side. Worst case scenario you can add them in both, although it will be nice to understand the internals of Shiny.    I need to stick to some structure for the modules, specially since I used them in several apps, so the idea to declare the libraries in each of them, adds verbosity and readability to the code.

Comment: I reckon that some guidelines would be helpful. For instance, a common package, let's say `ggplot2` may be used across modules. Should it be then loaded in `ui.R` only once? Would it be possible to avoid loading a package that may be used in a specific module that user may not interact with?

Comment: @Konrad I will add them at the `ui.R` side. As far as I know, either you add verbosity and risk not to have a function package loaded. Don't know a way to avoid redundancy.  Since shiny with modules is already complex enough, I go for the verbosity..

Comment: I load all libraries in global.R, and nothing in ui/server.R, but I'm not using modules.